# Odd character in HTML Table ï¾

Tags: html

I am working with very basic HTML Tables, it was going good untill I found this Character `<td>ï¾` on screen when it's not anywhere in my code.

With firebug HTML Tab if found this:

```
&lt; td &gt; ï¾ &nbsp;
```

No idea where it is coming from. Any guess or solution please?

Comment: Is the data coming from a database?

Comment: No, it's just basic HTML Table mark up.

Comment: check your file BOM encoding with notepad++ also give more information please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the solution there was a td tag as following:

```
<
                        td >ﾠ </td>
```

by doing it :

```
<td></td>
```

I fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an invalid character in your html. Find out what character is causing this and replace it with the relative fix here; http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm